# React Switch Input not triggering SetState on first Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good evening everyone,

I'm trying to implement a switch input to a component with handles data to display a chart with Chart.js. The chart I'm building is a scattered chart with some point having the label "Accepted" and others "Rejected". My issue comes with the switch which is supposed to allowed the user to display both "Accepted" and "Rejected" points.

My component is the one below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Scatter } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { SimulationResults } from '../SimulationResults';
    
export default class ScatterHeightLength extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ScatterData : {},
            AcceptedSwitch : false,
        }
    }
    
    ScatterDataConstructor (data){
        const HeightvsLength = data.map( result => { return { x : result.length, y : result.height} })
        const ColorHeightvsLength = data.map(result =>{ 
            return (result.Rejection === 'Accepted' ? "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)" : "rgba(255,131,192,0.4)")
        })
        return ({ScatterData: {
            labels : 'Scatter',
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : ["Accepted", "Rejected"],
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    borderColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    borderCapStyle: "butt",
                    borderDash: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: "miter",
                    pointBorderColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    pointBackgroundColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    pointHoverBorderColor: ColorHeightvsLength,
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: HeightvsLength,
                }
            ]
        }})
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ScatterData: this.ScatterDataConstructor(this.props.data).ScatterData});
        console.log(this.state.AcceptedSwitch, this.state.RejectedSwitch)
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(this.props.data !== prevProps.data){
            this.setState({ScatterData: this.ScatterDataConstructor(this.props.data).ScatterData});
            console.log(this.state.AcceptedSwitch, this.state.RejectedSwitch)
        }
    }  
    handleToggleAccepted = () =>{
        this.setState({ AcceptedSwitch: !this.state.AcceptedSwitch});
        console.log(this.state.AcceptedSwitch, this.state.RejectedSwitch)
        this.FilterChartData();   
    };
    FilterChartData =() =>{
        if (this.state.AcceptedSwitch && this.state.RejectedSwitch){
            return this.setState({ ScatterData: {} })
        }
        else if (this.state.AcceptedSwitch){
            const data = this.props.data.slice()
            for(var i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].Rejection === "Accepted"){
                    data.splice(i,1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return this.setState({ ScatterData: this.ScatterDataConstructor(data).ScatterData })
        }
        else if (this.state.RejectedSwitch){
            const data = this.props.data.slice()
            for(var i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].Rejection === "Rejected"){
                    data.splice(i,1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return this.setState({ ScatterData: this.ScatterDataConstructor(data).ScatterData })
        }
        else {
            return this.setState({ ScatterData: this.ScatterDataConstructor(this.props.data).ScatterData})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className = "row">
                <div className = "col-xl-12 h-50">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="card border-left-primary shadow mb-4 h-50">
                            <div className="card-header py-3">
                                <h6 className="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Height Versus Length </h6>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <Scatter
                                data = {this.state.ScatterData}
                                width={200}
                                height={400}
                                options={{ 
                                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                                    legend : {
                                        display :true,
                                        position : 'right'
                                    },
                                }}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id={"AcceptedSwitch" + this.props.keyforelement} onClick={this.handleToggleAccepted}/>
                                <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={"AcceptedSwitch" + this.props.keyforelement}>Toggle this switch element</label> 
                            </div>                          
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My issue comes when clicking the switch button for the first time, nothing happens, the state is not being changed (and when I console.log the state it shows that this.state.AcceptedSwitch is still false). But after the first click, the state do update and change the "AcceptedSwitch".

Can someone tells me what I'm missing here ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `setState` actions are asynchronous, you will need to call the `this.FilterChartData()` function in the setState callback in order to ensure that the state is up to date.

I think you should replace this :

```js
handleToggleAccepted = () =>{
  this.setState({ AcceptedSwitch: !this.state.AcceptedSwitch});
  console.log(this.state.AcceptedSwitch, this.state.RejectedSwitch)
  this.FilterChartData();   
};
```

By :

```js
handleToggleAccepted = () =>{
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    AcceptedSwitch: !prevState.AcceptedSwitch
  }), () => {
    this.FilterChartData();
  });
};
```

Let me know if this fix works!